# I cannot access the Excel interop from my VB program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, excel-interop

I have had to replace my laptop.  One of the applications I have needed to install is Visual Studio Community 2019 since I rely on some programs which I wrote in VB.  My memory of the 2015 version is that I just installed it.  With the 2019 version, I must specify which components I need.  Given how many components are available, I can see why they cannot install everything.  I need access the Excel interop and have downloaded every component that might give access to the interop without any apparent success.  The statement `Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` gives the error “{) Namespace Microsoft.  Namespace or type specified in the Imports ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel’ does not contain any public member or cannot be found.”

Searching for help, I found: “to use the features of a Microsoft Office application from an Office project, you must use the primary interop assembly (PIA) for the application.”  For my 64-bit computer, these should, apparently, be installed in “%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\”.

I find that folder “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\” contains subfolders “Office14” and “Office15”.  Each of these subfolders contains a different set of PIAs.  Both contain “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll” with the Office 14 version dated 31Mar2015 and the Office 15 version dated 7Oct2015.

I use Office version 15.  Should I move the PIAs I want from folder “PIA\Office15” to folder “PIA” or have I misunderstood something else?

Comment: The `Imports` statement does not add the reference to the project.  Use the Project Menu->Add Reference, then select the "COM" tab to select the appropriate "Microsoft Excel xx.y Object  Library".

Comment: @TnTinMn  Thanks for the suggestion but I had already tried "Add Reference". The InterOps are not listed.  A number of "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects" references are listed but I cannot find where they are held.

Comment: When you say "InterOps are not listed" are you saying the file 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll' is not in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15?  I right-clicked dependencies and selected 'Add COM Reference'.  Then I clicked the Browse button and went to the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15 and added the file Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll.  Did that not work for you?

Comment: When you install VSC, you are offered a limited number of options.  The InterOps are not among those options.  You have to install "Manage NuGet packages" and select the InterOps from the thousands of packages offered via it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to install the Nuget package `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` form `Nuget Package Manager`.
First, right click the project and select `Manage NuGet Packages...`.

[image]

Then type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` in the search bar and install it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Kyle Wang’s answer allowed me to solve my problem.  However, his images and descriptions differed from my experience with *Visual Studio 2019*.  I suspect he uses an earlier version.  This answer documents my experience with *Visual Studio Community 2019* in the hope that other can benefit from my troubles.

With *Visual Studio 2015*, the version I have been using, only *Visual Studio* is installed.  With *Visual Studio 2019*, *Visual Studio Installer* is also installed.

[image: Section of start menu showing Visual Studio and VS installer]

If I open *Visual Studio Installer* I see:

[image: Initial window for Visual Studio Installer]

If I click <kbd>Modify</kbd>, I see:

[image: VSI window showing first few Workloads]

If I scroll down a little I see:

[image: VSI window showing how previously downloaded Workloads are marked]

The blue ticks in the righthand corner identify the workloads I have already installed.

If I click <kbd>Individual Components</kbd>, I see:

[image: VSI Individual Components window showing most downloaded components]

I am unsure which components were downloaded because they were included in a selected workload and which were downloaded because I selected every component that might include the Excel InterOp I was looking for.  I will probably uninstall Visual Studio and re-install now I know what I need.

If I scroll down enough, I see:

[image: VSI Individual Components window showing NuGet components]

I definitely needed to download *NuGet package manager* if I want access to the Excel InterOp.  I do not know if I needed *NuGet targets and build tasks*.  If I re-install Visual Studio I will try without *NuGet targets and build tasks* and update this answer to report if it is needed.  I have not found any documentation describing the significance of these components, so it seems you need to experiment to determine what components you need.

Once you have selected the workloads and or individual components you want, click <kbd>Modify</kbd> in the bottom righthand corner.  A progress screen is displayed while the installation is performed.  When it has finished, close *Visual Studio Installer*.

Open Visual Studio 2019 and then create or open the solution that requires the Excel InterOp.  The fourth tab in the top row is <kbd>Project</kbd>.  Click it.  The bottom but one line in the dropdown menu is <kbd>Manage NuGet Packages…</kbd>.  Click it.  You will see:

[image: Initial window of Manage NuGet Packages]

Click <kbd>Browse</kbd> to get:

[image: Window of Manage NuGet Packages showing most downloaded packages]

https://www.nuget.org/ claims they hold 2,031,503 versions of 181,450 unique packages.  As far as I can tell, they are displayed in order of download numbers.  For example, Newtonsoft.Json has been downloaded 320.5 million times.  To find any particular package you must use search.  Searching for “microsoft.office.interop” reduces the list to something manageable with the Excel Interop at the top.  Select the package you need and click <kbd>Install</kbd> on the right.